# Is it possible to make jQuery Ajax() emulate HTML FORM accept-charset parameter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, svg

I'm posting SVG data to an action page using "accept-charset='utf-8'". On the action page I'm inserting that data into a table. Later, in another page, I query that data out of the table and run it through Batik to transcode it into a PNG file. It works well.

```
<form action="test_action.cfm" method="post" target="_blank" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

If I remove the accept-charset="utf-8" from the form tag then later (on the transcode page) I get an "Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence" error (when attempting to transcode).

Further I get the very same error every which way I attempt to use jQuery's .ajax() to attempt to handle the action page in the background. Using 'accept-charset="utf-8"' makes it all work.

Attempt at using $.ajax() to send the SVG to the action page in the background:

```
var lclSVG = $('#myDiv')[0].innerHTML;
$.ajax({
  url: "myAction.cfm",
  type: "POST",
  data: ({myInfo: lclSVG}),
});
```

Is there some way to post this data via $.ajax() while forcing .ajax() to do something like 'accept-charset="utf-8"'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX Character Encoding Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding-problem)

Comment: Not a duplicate but rather a restatement from a different perspective. Sorry if it was too similar; I won't submit anything like it again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JQuery ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the default already is UTF-8.  But maybe try to foce the setting anyhow, as per those docs, with the `contentType` option. You might also want to look at the `processData` option, as it specifically mentions XML handling.

I agree with your analysis, but have you verified that the corruption is occurring during the upload process, or some quirk to do with your transcoding ([more details against this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216397/jquery-ajax-seems-to-alter-svg-data-sent-to-coldfusion-server)): perhaps things are running *slightly* different between your normal file upload and your AJAX upload?

To eliminate this, rather than processing right through to transcoding, maybe just write the data to an SVG and test it before trying the transcoding (just as a troubleshooting step, I mean).

You might get some more hints as to what's going on by using Firebug to look at the request to the server that sends the file: compare the two approaches and look for differences.

Not an explicit answer, I'm afraid, but perhaps some stuff to look at.

Comment: thanks for responding. I have verified that it's happening when sending the data through .ajax(). Firebug didn't reveal much. I'm not sure how to "see" the change in character encoding. I've taken a new tack which is working very well. I put a form in a hidden div along with a zeroFrame. I'm using jQuery to submit to the frame and that action page posts the data to the table. It doesn't corrupt the data so roll-my-own-ajax was my solution...